# For a service created, Local system account have not enough credentials?

Tags: windows, service

Somebody created a service which runs an exe (in VB6). My part was to create this exe. If I run the exe using a bat file (exeApplication parameters), my program works fine. If I execute the service and runs the exe with the same parameters, not working completely/correctly.
Somebody tells me that is a issue with credentials. I mention that the service(is a process) runs with "Local System account".

How I can change this? I tried to change on option "This account" and put the user-computer but not saving this.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

The `NT Authority\System` account has the most power of any user account on the system. There is nothing that it cannot do, even if it first has to take ownership of an object or change its permissions, the System account can do it.

Your problem lies elsewhere. Maybe an environment variable or startup directory problem. When you launch a process in your own security context, that process will have different environment variables and startup/working directory than if Service Controller launches it as System.

Edit: As mfinni points out, I meant that local system has full control of the local system of course, no automatic permissions to remote computers. We don't know what your service does. If your service does use network resources, it is still possible to grant another machine's system account permissions on remote resources; it's tied to the machine's computer account in Active Directory.

Comment: 'There is nothing that it cannot do' *on the local system.* If the place where it's failing is trying to use resources on another server, it will have to run as an account that can do so -and if Marina is having problems setting that, we need to know the details there.

Comment: True of course. More detail from OP is definitely appreciated.